# Minified React error #31 happening randomly

Tags: reactjs

I have a dashboard for my app available in production and right after the login page I receive randomly this error.
As described in the details page it seems that the exact error is "*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {password}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*"
My problem is that this error happen only on some users (maybe 10 out of a 1000), and I can't find anything related to these users (seems to happen no matter the browser is). And even if I try to connect with the same credentials I can't reproduce this issue.
I don't even find anywhere in my code an array with a key password which would be rendered.

It's driving me crazy since I can't find a way to reproduce this error, and I may find difficult to ask my clients to make some random test on a development version to try to find a more precise error.

I suppose that most of you will think that without any more informations it will be impossible to help me, but I'm just throwing a message in a bottle so maybe someone reads it and say "Hey, I used this module and it seems that it's blocked by an ad blocker and it prevented me to render my page"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A stack trace for the error could help you narrow it down to the specific component producing the error.  You could then add more logging to that component to capture data being rendered when the problem happens.

Comment: Indeed but as I mentioned above, to get a stack trace I would need to ask my client to make some test on a development version of my app. Which seems difficult to ask.